# How to change only the date of git commit, and nothing else?

Tags: git

Googling yields this command:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$DATE" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$DATE"
```

But the above command also adds files to a commit when some other files have changes.

How to only change the date and nothing else?

Comment: That command won't add any files that weren't already staged; you might want to use `git stash` to set aside any staged files temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

`git commit --amend` adds any staged (`add`ed) changes to the commit. If you don't want those changes, don't add them before running commit. If you already have some changes added to the index, you can run `git reset` (without params) to remove any staged changes from the index.

Comment: your suggestion, or `git stash`as commented by @chepner